# RabbitMQ-C MinGW Build failure: poll() function not available on Windows

Tags: mingw, rabbitmq-c

I've tried compiling rabbitmq-c Version 0.6.0 (latest stable) using mingw (Version from 2013-10-27). The few compile errors are due to the use of the "include poll.h"; the required poll() function cannot be found.

The poll() function is not offered by mingw, so how could it be possible to compile current rabbitmq-c source using mingw, as described here:

https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/README-win32.md

Answer (score 0):

This poll() function will first be replaced with the select() function in Release 0.7.0 (currently unstable). So this means a stable, newer version of rabbitmq-c is NOTcurrently available for the windows platform.

I had overseen the comments in the project regarding the upcoming release 0.7.0.